# how to catch pdo statement error?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm doing some test with PDO and i found a "problem" with the try catch

i try to insert into a table "tryhard" 2 values, but this table have only one field(for the name) .

```
try{$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testpdomysql', 'root', '');
```

EDIT : i put

```
 $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

instead of

```
//$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING ); 



$pdo->beginTransaction();

$preparedStatement = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO tryhard VALUES (:nom ,:prenom)');
$preparedStatement->execute(array(
    'nom' => $_GET['nom'],
    'prenom' => $_GET['prenom'],
));

$pdo->commit();

echo "OK";
}
catch(Exception $e) {
$pdo->rollback();
echo "KO";
exit();
```

}

Ofc , it can't add it. i understand that, but i expect it will throw an exception in order to get in the catch. but it don't, and i feel quit f***.

So . What is the best way to get the error in this case? And shall i comment or not the second line?

Thinqs

Comment: using echo $e->getMessage();

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to halt your script in case of error, then no catch even required.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testpdomysql', 'root', '');
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
$pdo->beginTransaction();

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO tryhard VALUES (?, ?)');
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['nom'],$_GET['prenom']));
$pdo->commit();
```

With this code you will have error message logged, script halted and transaction rolled back in case of error

Note that for single query you don't need a transaction.

Comment: Thinqs for info . but no way to customize the error message logged ?

Comment: Why do you want to customize it?

Comment: well , cause it's very ugly ... and it don't explain a lot where the problem come from. but if there is no way , i will deal with it

Comment: How's that? You turned it upside down! The error message IS informative and DOES explain in detail where the problem come, providing you with full stack trace. What you want to change in it?

Answer (score 2):

A bad query does not throw an exception unless you set `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`.

Comment: $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); ty

Comment: how to catch the exception in this case? cause it don't go in the catch block ?

Comment: Use catch(PDOException $e) { }

Comment: The code you use should already work because `PDOException` just extends `Exception`.

Comment: @DanFromGermany , well , i expect it do , but i have no "KO" , i have Erreur : SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
NÂ° : 21S01

Comment: @ssbb this code you posted doesn't print anything like this. Please post in your question only ACTUAL CODE you runs in reality.

Answer (score -1):

For further information relating PDO Exceptions look at http://php.net/manual/de/class.pdoexception.php